# Realloc a structure in c

Tags: c, memory, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

So what I try to do is to dynamically allocate memory for a structure. The structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
   char name[N];
   int dimToys;
   TOY toys[N];
}CITY;
```

I read some input from a .txt file and copy it in my structure.

Then I have a function in which I would like to reallocate memory(and do some other irrelevant stuff) but my program works only when I use this function one single time. If I try to realloc the memory multiple times, then my program crashes.

It looks something like this:

```
void next_city(CITY** cityList, *dimCities, otherstuff){
    (*dimCities)++;
    *cityList = realloc(*cityList, (*dimCities) * sizeof(CITY*));
    otherstuff...
}
```

I tried running the debugger and it crashes at the line with realloc, when I call the function for the second time.
The call of the function in the main function looks like this:

```
 cityList = malloc(sizeof(CITY*));
 for(...){
     ...
     next_city(&cityList, &dimCities, otherstuff);
 }
```

I've already tried using a temporary variable for the reallocation and then copy it in my original `cityList`, but it doesn't work neither.

**LATER EDIT:**

Because a lot of people told me to update my question with some clarifications, I'll just show my code more clear, after I made some modifications from what you all told me.

```
void next_city(char line[], CITY **cityList, int *dimCities){
(*dimCities)++;
*cityList = realloc(*cityList, (*dimCities) * sizeof(CITY)); //UPDATE CITYLIST DIMENSION
cityList[(*dimCities) - 1]->dimToys = 0;

char *word = strtok(line, " ");
strcpy((cityList[(*dimCities) - 1]->name), word); //INSERET NAME OF THE CITY
word = strtok(NULL, " ");
strcpy((cityList[(*dimCities) - 1]->toys[cityList[(*dimCities) - 1]->dimToys].toyType), word); //INSERT NAME OF THE TOY
```

}

```
int main(){
int nrPasi;
int dimCities = 0;
scanf("%d", &nrPasi);
fgetc(stdin);
int i;
CITY *cityList;
cityList = NULL;

char line[100];
for(i = 0;i < nrPasi;i++){
    fgets(line, 100, stdin);
    next_city1(line, &cityList, &dimCities);
}
return 0;
```

}

So I basically read something like

```
3 
Berlin car
Berlin doll 
Madrid jacket
```

And I just want to read it step by step.
After I switched CITY* with CITY now realloc doesn't break my program, but it happens on the next line, when I try to access it. I get SISGEV

Comment: `*cityList = realloc(*cityList` - This is bad form. What happens in `realloc` fails

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: In code supplied you only allocate pointers to `CITY`. You don't allocate space for any structure. Is that correct and do you allocate space for the actual `CITY` structures elsewhere?

Comment: Specifically, how `*cityList` is allocated in first place?

Comment: “I tried running the debugger and it crashes at the line with realloc, when I call the function for the second time.” Saying it “crashes” isn’t particularly helpful. What *specifically* does the debugger say?

Comment: Voting to close for not including all relevant code, especially the declaration of the `cityList` in `main()`.

Comment: What is `N`? You need to give an [MCVE]

Comment: Yes, please update your question with an example where all *irrelevant* code has been removed, *but all relevant code (like the declaration of `cityList` in `main`, and anywhere you set `*cityList`) is present* (and verify that you still see the problem).

Answer (score 2):

You reallocate `sizeof(CITY*)`

That should be `sizeof(CITY)`, otherwise you allocate the size of a pointer.

That wouldn't be a problem if `cityList` is an array of poinetrs to `CITY`s, but from your code I do not see you next allocate memory for each `CITY`. So `citylist` is apparently an array of `CITY`s.

Because you assume `realloc` gave you storage for your struct, you started filling it with data. That will now overwrite the heap, causing your program to abort upon the next call to `realloc` because `realloc` now works on a corrupted heap.

Answer (score 2):

You're making a common mistake of allocating space for a pointer to `CITY` not the structure itself. You need to allocate `sizeof(CITY)`.

But there's a couple of other points to make...

```
cityList = NULL;//No need allocate anything up front.
dimCities=0u; //I'll assume this is size_t.
 for(...){
     ...
     if(next_city(&cityList, &dimCities /*, otherstuff*/)){
         //There was an error. What to do now?
     }
 }
```

And

```
int next_city(CITY** cityList, size_t *dimCities/*, otherstuff*/){
    (*dimCities)++;
    CITY* newList = realloc(*cityList, (*dimCities) * sizeof(CITY));
    if(newList==NULL){
        //out of memory..
        return 1;//Error return...
    }
    *cityList=newList;

    otherstuff...
    return 0;//Good return...
}
```

If you pass `NULL` to `realloc` it acts like `malloc()`.
I don't know how you propose to handle errors but if there's insufficient memory to reallocate `realloc()` does nothing and returns `NULL`.
Your way of allocating one object up front is fine. But personally this way is cleaner. Allocating at least one `CITY` may suit you because you never need to deal with `cityList==NULL`.

If this is a simple program you might just give up and `exit()` at this point. I've returned a error flag (a de facto C standard) so the surrounding program can handle it.

Comment: The de facto error return in C is 0 (FALSE). Only in `exit` is a non-zero value used as the failure exit of the program to the OS.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie In all my experience `return 0;` is success (no error) and any non-zero value indicates an error. That allows error information to be encoded in the return value - if useful. The same rule applies to `exit()` for the same rationale. It makes sense if you see the return value as an error code as false as 'False. There was no error'.

Comment: Think of it as a bool, with 0 is false and non-zero is true. You may be using another convention, but that is not standard C in my experience. E.g. `if (myFunc())` must now be coded as `if (!myFunc())` which clearly reads oposite of the meaning.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm surprised. I've never seen widespread use of 0 as failure in C code. I know it's slightly counter intuitive but as I said it allows richer error information. In the example one number could be 'out of memory' and another 'file read error'. But it is only norm. Tastes vary.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Here's a thought. My background in Windows and the convention is pretty much institutionalised there. What's yours? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137(v=vs.85).aspx.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: My bet goes on `-1` to indicate an error in C. And: What is `FALSE`? ;-)

Comment: @alk, `#define FALSE 0` and `#define TRUE 1`. Also: `#define VB_FALSE -1` which is either "Variant Boolean FALSE" or "Visual Basic False" and `#define VB_TRUE 0`. The fact that Micosoft uses that convention doesn't mean it is standard. If it were standard than the C standard would have defined true and false of boolean expresions differently.

Comment: @alk, Note that error returns can indeed be coded but then any value can be success and any value can be error. If you deviate from the C interpretation of true and false boolean expressions of ints, then you should compare the function return to a value and not ever write `if (!myFunc())` to test for success, butalways write `if (myFunc()==MY_SUCCESS)`. Alternatively error information can be passed in global variables of the module, just like `errno`.

Answer (score 1):

In the realloc, you use sizeof(CITY*). It seems to me that you tried to get the size of the CITY struct. So your code does not do that.

The size of CITY* is the size of the pointer holding the CITY struct, which is based on your system architecture (64 or 32 bit).
This way the content of CITY cannot pass between the reallocation, causing a memory buffer override and crashing the application.

If you need the size of the CITY struct just use sizeof(CITY)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are wanting to simply reallocate an array of pointers (to CITY) then the following works when I tested it. But as someone mentioned above, perhaps you want to have an array of CITY then you would want to allocate memory for CITY as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[10];
    int dimToys;
    int toys[10];
} CITY;

void next_city(CITY *** cityList, int *dimCities) {
    (*dimCities)++;
    *cityList = realloc(*cityList, (*dimCities) * sizeof(CITY*));
}

main(){
    CITY ** cityList;
    int dimCities=0;
    int i;

    cityList = malloc(sizeof(CITY*));
    printf("%p\n",  (void *) cityList); // print out the address of the memory allocated
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
        next_city(&cityList, &dimCities);
        malloc(1);  // malloc more data to force some fragmenation so that you can see that realloc does something interesting.
        printf("%p\n",  cityList); // print out the address of the reallocated memory
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Assuming you are wanting to simply reallocate an array of pointers*" why? `CITY * citylist` would not allow doing so.

Comment: In C only values of `void`-pointers may be printed. `u` is for unsigned integers. To print a `void`-pointer use `p` and cast the pointer to `void*`.